# Loop all words with VBA in MS Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I can loop all words with this:

```
        For Each wort In ActiveDocument.Words
...
        Next wort
```

But this include all paragraphs marks, partial words, and punctuation and words with hyphens are splittet (Abc-def will be Abc, - and def)

Is there a way to get (only) the "real" words?

Comment: What is a "real" word in your application? Is it in English? are you only interested in alphabetical (or alphanumeric) characters to make words?

Comment: for such a case I would make a list  (in some other file, Excel or any can be opened by MS Office) of ignored words (paragraph marks, punctuation etc) put it in a dictionary and checked each loop  with special function. You can do it even easier - you can check the ASCII code with  [Asc function](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/asc-function)   The same with words with hyphens are splitted - put a special function to check if there is a hyphen then we put together previous and following words in one.

Comment: Also possible to check length of words - if length of the word >1 (with len()) then it's exactly not special mark.

Answer (score 0):

OK this is my implementation of Advanced **[Words object (Word)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.words)**

```vb
Sub Loop_all_words_with_VBA_in_MS_Word()
    Dim wds As VBA.Collection, wd As Range, d As Document
    Set d = ActiveDocument
    Set wds = Loop_all_words_with_VBA_in_MS_Word_GetWords(d)
    For Each wd In wds
    
        Rem do what you want
        
        Rem the four lines below are for checking it out only
        wd.Select 'just for test to check out
        wd.Document.ActiveWindow.ScrollIntoView wd 'just for test to check out
        Stop 'just for test to check out
'        If wd.Text = "splittet" Then Stop'just for test


    Next wd
End Sub

Function Loop_all_words_with_VBA_in_MS_Word_GetWords(d As Document) As VBA.Collection
    Dim s As Long, rng As Range, wd As word.Range, wds As word.Range, cln As New VBA.Collection ', d As Document, dEnd As Long
    Dim symbols As String
    symbols = ",...;'""?:-_/*+()[]{}" & Chr(7) & Chr(9) & Chr(10) & Chr(11) & Chr(13)
    'Set d = ActiveDocument
    'dEnd = d.Range.End
    Set rng = d.Range
    With rng.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .ClearAllFuzzyOptions
        .Text = " "
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        While .Execute()
            Set wd = d.Range(s, rng.Start)
            s = VBA.InStr(wd.Text, VBA.Chr(13))
            If s And wd.Text <> Chr(13) Then
                Set wds = wd
                While s 'VBA.InStr(wds.Text, Chr(13))
                    Set wd = wds.Characters(1)
                    s = wd.Start
                    wd.SetRange s, s + wd.MoveUntil(Chr(13))
                    GoSub addword
                    wds.Start = wd.End + 1 '1=Len(Chr(13)
                    Do Until wds.Characters(1) <> Chr(13)
                        wds.Start = wds.Start + 1
                    Loop
                    s = VBA.InStr(wds.Text, VBA.Chr(13))

                Wend
                Set wd = wds
                GoSub addword
            Else
                GoSub addword
            
            End If
            s = rng.End
        Wend
    End With
    Set wd = d.Range(rng.End, d.Range.End - 1)
    GoSub addword
    
    Set Loop_all_words_with_VBA_in_MS_Word_GetWords = cln
    
    
    Exit Function
    
addword:
    If VBA.InStr(symbols, wd.Text) = 0 And wd.Text <> vbNullString Then
        If VBA.InStr(symbols, VBA.Right(wd.Text, 1)) Then
            wd.End = wd.End - 1
        End If
        If VBA.InStr(symbols, VBA.Left(wd.Text, 1)) Then
            wd.Start = wd.Start + 1
        End If

        cln.Add wd
    End If
    Return
End Function
```

- OK, and this is a *Range* version(previous is a document version):

```vb
Sub Loop_all_words_with_VBA_in_MS_Word()
    Dim wds As VBA.Collection, wd As Range, d As Document
    Set d = ActiveDocument
    If Selection.Type = wdSelectionIP Then
        Set wds = Loop_all_words_with_VBA_in_MS_Word_GetWords(d.Range)
    Else
        Set wds = Loop_all_words_with_VBA_in_MS_Word_GetWords(Selection.Range)
    End If
    For Each wd In wds
    
        Rem do what you want
        
        Rem the four lines below are for checking it out only
        wd.Select 'just for test to check out
        wd.Document.ActiveWindow.ScrollIntoView wd 'just for test to check out
        Stop 'just for test to check out
'        If wd.Text = "splittet" Then Stop'just for test


    Next wd
End Sub

Function Loop_all_words_with_VBA_in_MS_Word_GetWords(rng As word.Range) As VBA.Collection
    Dim s As Long, wd As word.Range, wds As word.Range, cln As New VBA.Collection, d As Document, rngEnd As Long ', rng As Range
    Dim symbols As String
    symbols = ",...;'""?:-_/*+()[]{}" & Chr(7) & Chr(9) & Chr(10) & Chr(11) & Chr(13)
    Set d = rng.Document
    s = rng.Start
    If VBA.Right(rng, 1) = Chr(13) Then rng.End = rng.End - 1
    rngEnd = rng.End
    'Set rng = d.Range
    With rng.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .ClearAllFuzzyOptions
        .Text = " "
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        Do While .Execute()
            If rngEnd < rng.End Then Exit Do
            Set wd = d.Range(s, rng.Start)
            s = VBA.InStr(wd.Text, VBA.Chr(13))
            If s And wd.Text <> Chr(13) Then
                Set wds = wd
                While s 'VBA.InStr(wds.Text, Chr(13))
                    Set wd = wds.Characters(1)
                    s = wd.Start
                    wd.SetRange s, s + wd.MoveUntil(Chr(13))
                    GoSub addword
                    wds.Start = wd.End + 1 '1=Len(Chr(13)
                    Do Until wds.Characters(1) <> Chr(13)
                        wds.Start = wds.Start + 1
                    Loop
                    s = VBA.InStr(wds.Text, VBA.Chr(13))

                Wend
                Set wd = wds
                GoSub addword
            Else
                GoSub addword
            
            End If
            s = rng.End
        Loop
    End With
    Set wd = d.Range(s, rngEnd)
    GoSub addword
    
    Set Loop_all_words_with_VBA_in_MS_Word_GetWords = cln
    
    
    Exit Function
    
addword:
    If VBA.InStr(symbols, wd.Text) = 0 And wd.Text <> vbNullString Then
        If VBA.InStr(symbols, VBA.Right(wd.Text, 1)) Then
            wd.End = wd.End - 1
        End If
        If VBA.InStr(symbols, VBA.Left(wd.Text, 1)) Then
            wd.Start = wd.Start + 1
        End If

        cln.Add wd
    End If
    Return
End Function
```

### Amendments to Words

Or we just can do to revise and enhance the **Words** object, maybe we'll get better performance.

```vb
Sub Loop_all_words_with_VBA_in_MS_Word()
    Dim wds As VBA.Collection, wd As Range, d As Document
    Set d = ActiveDocument
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    If Selection.Type = wdSelectionIP Then
        Set wds = Loop_all_words_with_VBA_in_MS_Word_GetWordsByWords(d.Range)
    Else
        Set wds = Loop_all_words_with_VBA_in_MS_Word_GetWordsByWords(Selection.Range)
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    For Each wd In wds
    
        Rem do what you want
        
        Rem the four lines below are for checking it out only
        wd.Select 'just for test to check out
        wd.Document.ActiveWindow.ScrollIntoView wd 'just for test to check out
        Stop 'just for test to check out
'        If wd.Text = "splittet" Then Stop'just for test


    Next wd
End Sub

Function Loop_all_words_with_VBA_in_MS_Word_GetWordsByWords(rng As word.Range) As VBA.Collection
    Dim wd As Range, cln As New VBA.Collection, d As Document, wdx As String
    Dim symbols As String
    Dim hyphenOpen As Boolean ', i As Long
    symbols = ",...¡K;'""?:-_/*+()[]{} " & Chr(7) & Chr(9) & Chr(10) & Chr(11) & Chr(13)
    Set d = rng.Document
    For Each wd In rng.Words
        'i = i + 1
        wdx = wd.Text
        If Not hyphenOpen Then
            If wdx <> vbNullString And VBA.Replace(wdx, " ", "") <> vbNullString Then
                If VBA.InStr(symbols, wd.Text) = 0 Then
                    If VBA.InStr(symbols, VBA.Right(wd.Text, 1)) Then
                        wd.End = wd.End - 1
                    End If
                    If VBA.InStr(symbols, VBA.Left(wd.Text, 1)) Then
                        wd.Start = wd.Start + 1
                    End If
                    
                    If wd.Text <> vbNullString Then cln.Add wd
                    
                Else
                    If VBA.Left(wd.Text, 1) = "-" Then
                        If VBA.InStr(symbols, wd.Next.Text) = 0 Then
                            hyphenOpen = True
                            cln(cln.Count).SetRange cln(cln.Count).Start, wd.End
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Else
            If wdx = " " Or wdx = vbNullString Or VBA.Replace(wdx, " ", "") = vbNullString Then
                hyphenOpen = False
            Else
                
                If VBA.InStr(symbols, wd.Text) = 0 Then
                    If VBA.InStr(symbols, VBA.Right(wd.Text, 1)) Then
                        wd.End = wd.End - 1
                    End If
                    If VBA.InStr(symbols, VBA.Left(wd.Text, 1)) Then
                        wd.Start = wd.Start + 1
                    End If
                    
                    If wd.Text <> vbNullString Then
                        cln(cln.Count).SetRange cln(cln.Count).Start, wd.End
                        'cln.Add wd
                    End If
                    hyphenOpen = False
                    
                Else
                    If VBA.Left(wd.Text, 1) = "-" Then
                        hyphenOpen = True
                        'cln(cln.Count).SetRange cln(cln.Count).Start, wd.End
                    End If
                End If
                
            End If
        
        End If
    Next wd
    Set Loop_all_words_with_VBA_in_MS_Word_GetWordsByWords = cln
End Function
```